# Nginx 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port only on PHP files

Tags: http, nginx, https, bad-request

I receive the following message by requesting a php file on my server:

400 Bad Request - The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.

But this only happens if I want to open a php file.

Forexample Index.html works, but Index.php not.

This is my Nginx config:

```
# Default server configuration
#


#Backend
upstream server_backend {
        server my.domain.com:80;
        server my.domain.com:443;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.domain.com;
#       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;

}
#HTTPS server
server {
listen 443 default ssl;
server_name my.domain.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        autoindex on;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/server.key;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 99999;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param https on;
                #revproxy
                proxy_pass  http://server_backend;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

E: Ok I found out that it's the reverse proxy ..

but how can I use the reverse proxy AND https the same time?

Comment: It seems that your `server_backend` has one http server and one https server. You should only populate servers which support the same protocol that you request in the `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: mhh sadly thats not the problem .. I changed it but it won't work :/